# Setting a function equal to a boolean in python

Tags: python

I'm writing a driver in Python 2.6 and I need it to be reverse compatible with a previous implementation (I don't have access to the source code).

```
class new_driver ():

     def output(self, state):

          if state == True:
              self.set_ouput_on()
          else:
              self.set_output_off()

              ...
```

The odd thing is that to keep compatibility I have to pass this output using the format

```
nd = new_driver()
nd.output = True
```

How do I pass a value in this way?

Edit:  To clarify: my "output" function has to receive the value True in this way in order to execute the function self.set_output_on()

Comment: So, your recipient expects `nd.output` to be boolean or what?

Comment: Why 2.6? And where do you want to pass it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the `@property` decorator:

```
@property
def output(self):
    return self... #not sure how you are tracking output on/off

@output.setter
def output(self, state):
    if state:
        self.set_output_on()
    else:
        self.set_output_off()
```

Comment: I did a fair bit of research on decorators (I'm a python noob) but I don't really understand what the build in `property` function is/does.  Also I understand the possible use of `@output` but am confused about what `.setter` is/does.